# Char Array being messed up while mutating other data in a binary file

Tags: c++, struct, binaryfiles

While mutating a file with data only of this structure

```
const int NAME_SIZE = 31;
struct Department// data struct for departments
{
    int departmentID;
    char departmentName[NAME_SIZE],
        departmentHeadName[NAME_SIZE];
};
```

mutating the data in the file it appears to truncate my old data/write over stuff it shouldn't, with the following data test care with the data in order depID, depName, DepHeadName.

structure 1 `1` `Department1` `DepHead1`
structure 2 `2` `Department2` `DepHead2`

this is before mutating it with * being unreadable characters

```
****Department1********************DepHead1*w***n***]****¾*ó*****0*****Department2********************DepHead2*w***n***]****¾*ó*****0*
```

The next segment being the first one but passed through the bottom code segment to mutate structure 2 with the data "Department2Mut" and "DepHead2Mut"

```
*****************************************************************Department2Mut**S **********P"\DepHead2Mut**èI³*S **********à***
```

The code segment somehow makes all the char arrays unreadable, but keeps the departmentID intact(when run through a function to check data department ID shows up but other variables are blank)
With some other test cases, iv'e found that it deletes all data after the one you mutated and ruins all the char arrays before it.

```
    depOUT.departmentID = depIN.departmentID;//makes departmentID whatever ID of the department want changed
    cout << "EDIT the Department Data:\n";//fancy output
    cout << "Dept Name: ";
    cin >> depOUT.departmentName;//assigns departmentName char array
    cout << "\nHead of Dept Name: ";
    cin >> depOUT.departmentHeadName;// assigns departmentHeadName char array
    fstream departmentWrite("departments.dat", ios::out|ios::binary);//creates fstream object for file io
    if (!departmentWrite) //checks if file opens 
    {
        cout << "Error in opening the file.";
        return;
    }
    departmentWrite.seekg((depNum - 1) * sizeof(depOUT), ios::beg);//searches by starting at start then multiplying size by index depNum being how many departments there are in the file
    departmentWrite.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&depOUT), sizeof(depOUT));//actually writes the structure
```

Basically code messes with all the data in the file when it's not supposed to

Comment: I highly recommend filling the name arrays with spaces before input into them.  That will get rid of the strange characters in the name.

Comment: Will do, thank you for the tip

Comment: If you're writing, shouldn't you be using `seekp` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Found out issue, the fstream must be declared with ios::in also or else it will mess with char arrays and delete all data after the mutated set.